# The value for the given [key], or null if [key] is not in the map

Tags: flutter, dart, null, mapping

`

```
  var _finalscore = 0;
  var _index = 0;
  final _question = [
    {
      'Questionkey': "which cryptocurrency do you like",
      'Answer': [
        {'text': 'bitcoin', 'score': 1},
        {'text': 'etherium', 'score': 0}
      ]
    },
    {
      'Questionkey': "and why do you like that?",
      'Answer': [
        {'text': 'stable', 'score': 1},
        {'text': 'i don\'t know actually', 'score': 0}
      ]
    },
  ];
  void _printanswer() {
    if ((_question[_index]['Answer']['score'] == 1)) {
      _finalscore = _finalscore + 1;
    }

    setState(() {
      _index++;
    });
  }
```

`

i want to update the finalscore if the score is 1
the question is list which consists of maps and again list,map , i want to retrive the score value to check whether the selected one has score value 0 or 1 and compare to update the final value

the code error is :
The value for the given [key], or null if [key] is not in the map.

Some maps allow null as a value. For those maps, a lookup using this operator cannot distinguish between a key not being in the map, and the key being there with a null value. Methods like [containsKey] or [putIfAbsent] can be used if the distinction is important.

The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: actually in the code _question[_index}['answer']['score']==1 condition,  i want to get the value of the score of the selected question and when I try to do it, it gives me an error at ['score'] and says the value of the given key or null if [key] is not in the map

Answer (score 0):

in the if condition you have to write the as integer keyword

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).